# Make a div clickable using a render array

Tags: 7, theming

What is the (best) way to make a div clickable using a render array in code?

I am creating a module that outputs a title in a rounded box, so I use the markup type and specify a class with #prefix and #suffix and apply some css on that class. This gets me a box, but I want to make the box clickable with a different url for each box. What would be a good way to do this?

I could put an onclick in the prefix or put  in the prefix and  in the suffix. But both are not very pretty.

I'm using Drupal 7 and would like not to use additional modules like views.

Comment: I take it you are creating a link here?

Comment: Yes, the divs should be links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some more digging and came across the container type. This is imo the best way to achieve this.

You use a container as wrapper to which you assign the class and onclick attributes. Then with markup you put whatever you want inside the container/div. It is possible to put more items in the container simply by adding more children to the $divwrapper class.

This is the code I ended up with (for several titles/boxes):

```
  $titles = array(1 => 'title 1', 2 => 'title 2', 3 => 'title 3');
  $output = array();
    foreach ($titles as $id => $title) {
      $onclick = "location.href='/node/{$id}'";
      $divwrapper = array(
          '#type' => 'container',
          '#attributes' => array('class' => array('rounded_box'), 'onclick' => $onclick)
      );
      $divwrapper["box_{$id}"] = array('#markup' => "<p>{$title}</p>");
      $output[] = $divwrapper;
    }
  return $output;
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to create an Accordion, I would look at [Views Accordion](http://drupal.org/project/views_accordion) because it sounds like what you want. I would try to stay away from custom javascript and html and attempt to theme views_accordion as you want it to look.

Comment: Thanks. I put some additional info in the question. I want to do this in code.